# Browsing files of hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running hadoop in ubuntu and my hdfs itself appears to work: a command line like `hadoop fs -ls /` returns a result, and the namenode web interface at `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp` comes up. 
However, when I click on the "Browse the filesystem" link on this page I get a 404 Error. The error
 message displayed in the browser reads:

> Problem accessing /browseDirectory.jsp. Reason:
>       /browseDirectory.jsp

The URL in the browser bar at this point is `http://0.0.0.0:50070/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/`.

Comment: Edit your question with your `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` and also namenode logs in `logs` folder

Comment: If you change the 0.0.0.0 to localhost, does the page render?

Comment: solution found: my data node was  not running.